# Create user fails on PMA 4.5.0 with MariaDB 10.0.17

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

When trying to create a new user in phpMyAdmin 4.5.0 on a MariaDB database I get a "1065 - Query was empty" error above the printed query and "The selected user was not found in the privilege table." right on top of the user creation wizard.

Also when I try to edit the query inline, the highlighting complains about an unrecognized statement type "WITH".

The full query as created by phpMyAdmin looks like this:

```
CREATE USER 'asd'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '***';GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'asd'@'%' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

The syntax highlighting complains about the with in "WITH mysql_native_password" and about the word "USAGE" in the GRANT statement.
I don't really know why phpMyAdmin explicitly names the authentication plugin/mechanism when it's using the default and only installed MySQL native password.

When I remove the "WITH mysql_native_password" part from the query it executes just fine. (Obviously I entered the password which was removed/replaced with asterisks by phpMyAdmin in that query again)

So is this authentication plugin stuff a setting I can change somewhere or is this a bug in phpMyAdmin with MariaDB backend?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a bug in phpMyAdmin... According to MariaDB docs  the right way to create an user with mysql_native_password plugin is `CREATE USER mysqltest_up1 IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING '*E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB';`

I haven't found an issue in phpMyAdmin page, so i've opened one:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11520

Docs page: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/development-pluggable-authentication/

Comment: Just encountered same problem and tested. This fixed it for me. One can use the "edit inline" to replace the `BY` into `USING` and the `***` by the actual password. Thanks.

Comment: There is apparently a fix in the works for 4.5.1 and already up on their demo instance. That accepted fix is currently not using the pluggable authentication at all for MariaDB instead of just fixing the syntax.
After a small remark, there's now another pull request which fixes the syntax and (as far as I understood) will allow user-defined authentication plugins to be used in addition to the two native MySQL modules. I'm not sure whether that will be accepted for 4.5.1, though.